# I don't understand how 雇い入れる is different from 雇う

Tags: word-choice

> ［動ラ下一］［文］やとひい・る［ラ下二］**新たに**雇う。「新卒者を―・れる」([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/222247/meaning/m0u/%E9%9B%87%E3%81%84%E5%85%A5%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/))

I don't understand what the 新たに is doing here...? I've read example sentences with 雇う and 雇い入れる and I can't perceive the difference...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

雇い入れる means to newly take someone into employment. 雇う can mean the same thing, but it also means to have/keep someone as an employee.

> - 彼を10年間雇い続けた。: OK
> - 彼を10年間雇い入れ続けた。: NG
> - 彼女を雇い入れるのをやめた。: (i.e., she could not enter this company)
> - 彼女を雇うのをやめた。: (also means she was fired)

Answer (score -1):

According the dictionary あらた【新た】 means "again", "once more":
改めて行う
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/新た/#je-1881](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%96%B0%E3%81%9F/#je-1881)

So 新たに雇う means "to hire again", "to hire more people".

雇う simply means "to hire".

Comment: The dictionary entry you linked says 新た means both "new(ly)" and "once again." In this case, 新た in 新たに雇う is the former. But you can use 新たに雇い入れる to say "to hire more people."